# する気 vs 積もり Suru verb + Ki vs Tsumori

Tags: word-choice

Can they both be interchangeable?

For e.g.　殺す気でやったんです　vs　殺す積もりでやったんです、

Comment: In this meaning つもり is usually written in kana.

Answer (score 3):

In that particular sentence, 「気{き}」 and 「つもり」 would be interchangeable; That's a given.

> "I did it with an intention to kill him/her/them."

The two words would be mostly interchangeable when talking about events in the past, present and near future.

I would, however, feel somewhat awkward about using 「気」 to talk about events in the far future.　Using 「つもり」 would be more natural.